# Javascript chartAt is not a function at UDF$1(STRING)

Tags: google-bigquery, bigquery-udf

I have the following function to convert any string to title case:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION udf.title_case(str STRING)
  RETURNS STRING
  LANGUAGE js AS """
  return str
          .replace(/([^\\W_]+[^\\s-]*) */g, function(txt){return txt.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + txt.substr(1).toLowerCase();})
  """;
```

UPDATE:

I fixed `chartAt` to `charAt` and still get the same error

and it produces the following error:

```
"project.dataset.charAt" is not a function at UDF$1(STRING) line 3, columns 110-111
```

I can bypass this error by using `[]` notation which is not ideal however I hit the same error with `substr`.

I normally test my functions in JSBin or similar and works fine but when translate it to Bigquery I need to escape `\` in regex and then deal with these out of the blue errors.

Makes life harder for those who are not experienced in the arts of JS programming.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: To test your regex, you can use the tool at regex101.com then pick golang. Google products use another version of regex.

Comment: @KaBoom the regex function work. Problem is bigquery not recognizing `charAt`

Comment: I know your regex works, just a info for you :)

Comment: cool thanks! I misunderstood your comment :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You write the wrong function name, "char[t]At" instead of "charAt".
I use temp function to test

```
CREATE TEMP FUNCTION tempFunc(str STRING)
  RETURNS STRING
  LANGUAGE js AS """
  return str
          .replace(/([^\\W_]+[^\\s-]*) */g, function(txt){return txt.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + txt.substr(1).toLowerCase();})
  """;


  select tempFunc("abce")
```

and the result is "Abce".
You can try this query in your bigquery editor

Comment: It's also taken me 20 mins to figure out

Comment: i still get `charAt" is not a function at UDF$1(STRING) line 3,`

Comment: I edit my answer with the fixed-function @Altons

Answer (score 1):

Consider use of [INITCAP](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators#initcap) function instead of JS UDF

It takes a STRING and returns it with the first character in each word in uppercase and all other characters in lowercase

for example

```
SELECT INITCAP('I have the following function to convert any string to title case:')
```

produces below output

[image]

Comment: I wished I new this before - it'd have saved a lot of headaches. However I am interested in the JS error so will wait for another answer before approving this one. Thanks anyway